# Mutual Information implementation return NaN

Tags: python, mutual-information

I'm trying to implement MI algorithm.
here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from copy import copy
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

data, labels = load_digits(return_X_y=True) # labels is Y vector #data shape = (1797, 64), and labels shape is (1797,1)
(n_samples, n_features), n_digits = data.shape, np.unique(labels).size

#normalize the data and set into DataFrame
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
d = scaler.fit_transform(data)
```

now here my implementation for MI:

```
def mi_algo(_data, _labels, size, defualt_x = 17, defualt_y = 10):  

 theta = np.zeros(_data.shape[1])
 x_len = y_len = _data.shape[0]
 py =  np.array([len(_labels[_labels==y_val])/y_len for y_val in range(defualt_y)]) #P(y)

 for col in range(len(theta)):
  temp = np.copy(_data[:,col])
  px =  np.array([len(temp[temp==x_val])/x_len for x_val in range(defualt_x)]) #P(x)
  for x in range(defualt_x):
   if px[x] == 0:
    continue
   for y in range(defualt_y):
    if py[y] == 0: 
      continue
    pxy = np.sum((temp == x) & (labels == y)) #P(x,y)
    pxy = np.divide(pxy,x_len)
    yx = np.multiply(px[x],py[y])
    pxy = np.divide(pxy, yx)
    log = np.log2(pxy)
    theta[col] += np.multiply(pxy,log)


 return theta
```

I used all the np because I got some error.
here is the output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:23: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:24: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
[ 0. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan  0. nan nan nan
 nan nan nan  0. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
```

now, I understand there is some divide by zero, but I can't figure it out. Thnx for you help!

Comment: You can help others help you by trying to ask a more focused question; as it stands, the only thing a person could do is to run your code and see what happens -- it's not really reasonable to expect that. A couple of things for you to look at. One is that MI = an average of log(something)/log(something else) -- is any term equal to zero? Another is, try a simpler example for which you know the answer. E.g. try an example for which MI = 0 by construction. What is the maximum value of MI? Try to construct an example for that too.

Comment: @RobertDodier thnx, I didn't expect someone will run my code, just a little review. I know there are some zeros inside the log as the warning said, but all the test I'd run over, all the parameters were not a zero

Comment: Have you tried adding an epsilon value to your yx to see whether it makes NaNs go away? Something like 1e-8 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slove it by check if the divisor is 0 -> continue.